# the error is "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined" and Uncaught ReferenceError: ipcRenderer is not defined

Tags: electron

I'm new to electron.js and created a desktop app but facing the error and won't able to resolve . i just wanted to create a app so that my app will fetch the api load a url on login and after that i wanted to create a script to do some checking methods lets forget this but when i implemented the code these 2 errors are occuring again and again
here is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Login Page</title>
  <script src="preload.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Login to Your App</h1>
  <form id="loginForm">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
  </form>

  <script>
    if (typeof window.myAPI !== 'undefined') { // Check for myAPI object
      document.getElementById('loginForm').addEventListener('submit', async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const username = event.target.username.value;
        const password = event.target.password.value;

        try {
          const response = await window.myAPI.invoke('login', { username, password });
          if (response === 'success') {
            console.log('Login successful');
            window.myAPI.send('login-success'); // Use window.myAPI to send the event
          } else {
            console.log('Login failed');
            // Show error message or take appropriate action
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error occurred during login:', error);
          // Handle the error, show an error message, etc.
        }
      });

      // Listen for the 'login-success' event using the exposed function
      window.myAPI.onLoginSuccess(() => {
        console.log('Login success event received');
        const attendanceScript = document.createElement('script');
        attendanceScript.src = 'attendancechecker.js';
        attendanceScript.onload = () => {
          console.log('Attendance checker script loaded.');
          // Now you can perform your attendance checking logic
        };
        document.body.appendChild(attendanceScript);
      });
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

and here is my preload.js

```
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('myAPI', {
  onLoginSuccess: (listener) => {
    ipcRenderer.on('login-success', listener);
  },
});
```

and this is the method that i implemented in main.js

```
ipcMain.handle('login', (event, loginData) => {
  const { username, password } = loginData;
  // Perform your login logic here
  const isValidUser = true;

  if (isValidUser) {
    // If the login is successful, load the main app page
    mainWindow.loadURL('http:some_url/?access_token=my_token');
    mainWindow.show();
    console.log("success event retured");
    return 'success';
  } else {
    // If the login fails, show an error or take appropriate action
    console.log("failure event retured");
    return 'failure';
  }
});
```

i know i'm giving hardcoded token but its only for the testing purpose.
and this is my browserWindow function.

```
function createWindow() {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: false,
      contextIsolation: true,
      webSecurity: false,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
      
    },
  });
```

i tried many different methods 1st i tried to make preload.js from this // preload.js

```
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

// Expose the ipcRenderer object to the renderer process
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('ipcRenderer', ipcRenderer);
```

to this

```
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('myAPI', {
  onLoginSuccess: (listener) => {
    ipcRenderer.on('login-success', listener);
  },
});
```

but after that i was facing same issue then i don't know what i have done my Uncaught ReferenceError: ipcRenderer is not defined this error solved but still getting 1st error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your HTML file you load the `preload.js` script. You should not do that, Electron handles it for you when you specify `preload` in the `webPreferences`.

```html
<head>
  <title>Login Page</title>
  <!-- <script src="preload.js"></script> <- Remove this -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
```

Also, for [security reasons](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/context-isolation#security-considerations), make sure you don't directly expose IPC functions nor the whole IPC API (as on the 1st method you tried). You need to update these `window.myAPI.invoke` and `window.myAPI.send` accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for reply that works for me and i hope you are giving me the suggestion for change in preload.js as contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('myAPI', { invoke: (channel, ...args) => ipcRenderer.invoke(channel, ...args), send: (channel, ...args) => ipcRenderer.send(channel, ...args), onLoginSuccess: (listener) => { ipcRenderer.on('login-success', listener); }, }); correct me if i'm wrong.